# Why the compiler tells 'Expression was too complex'

Tags: xcode, swift

I write this code in Xcode, you can try it on playground.

```
let constraintSize = CGSize(width: 500.0 - 55.0 - 35.0 - 60.0 - 10.0 - 15.0, height: 9999)
```

the compiler tell this message

`expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

[image: too complex expression in Swift]

Any ideas why the compiler tell this silly message, since it is clear that it's just a simple calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't like to have expressions as function parameters.

I guess it's more a *source code parsing* problem than a *calculation* problem.

The solution is obvious:

```
let width = 500.0 - 55.0 - 35.0 - 60.0 - 10.0 - 15.0
let constraintSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 9999)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously this is a language issue. Compiler should have been able to execute this simple expression. However, in some cases its been observed that long expressions eat up 100% CPU leading to deadlock.

Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550775/if-condition-failing-with-expression-too-complex) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810625/xcode-beta-6-1-and-xcode-6-gm-stuck-indexing-for-weird-reason/25813625#25813625) for more information. Guess you already know the solution in your case so not posting it :).