# Swift: [String: String] is not identical to CGFloat (SwiftJSON)

Tags: json, dictionary, swift

I am using `SwiftyJSON` to parse a `JSON array` and can't figure out why I can't use the values when parsing the array to populate a `Dictionary`.

```
var dictionary = [String: String]()
    for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json[myArray] {
        let name = subJson["name"].string
        let value = subJson["value"].string
        gameOwned += [name: value]
    }
```

I am receiving this error on this line:

```
gameOwned += [name: value]
```

Am I adding it to the empty dictionary wrong? I have already tested the values of `name` and `value` and they println with no problems.

Comment: Try `dictionary[name] = value`

Comment: Try `gameOwned! += [name: value]`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this code:

```swift
func authParam(withParams: [String: AnyObject?]) -> [String: AnyObject?] {
    var params: [String: AnyObject?] = ["user_nonce": self.user_nonce, "user_identifier": self.user_identifier];
    params += withParams; //Error

    return params;
}
```

I found out that concatenating two dictinaries with

```
var a = ["one": "a"]
a += ["two": "b"]
```

is wrong because this way you are concatenating two arrays not dictionaries - so swift is expecting an array with CGFloat as key.

I found a solution [here at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26728685/2753395). Just Extend the dictionary class and add a merge function

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func merge<K, V>(dict: [K: V]){
        for (k, v) in dict {
            self.updateValue(v as Value, forKey: k as Key)
        }
    }
}
```

so now i can merge my dictionaries without a lot of effort

```
func authParam(withParams: [String: AnyObject?]) -> [String: AnyObject?] {
    var params: [String: AnyObject?] = ["user_nonce": self.user_nonce, "user_identifier": self.user_identifier];

    params.merge(withParams); //works fine

    return params;
}
```