# How to deep merge 2 Swift dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary

My question is simple, I want to know how to do a deep merge of 2 Swift dictionaries (not NSDictionary).

```
let dict1 = [
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": [
        "d": 3
    ],
    "f": 2
]

let dict2 = [
    "b": 4,
    "c": [
        "e": 5
    ],
    "f": ["g": 6]
]

let dict3 = dict1.merge(dict2)

/* Expected:

dict3 = [
    "a": 1,
    "b": 4,
    "c": [
        "d": 3,
        "e": 5
    ],
    "f": ["g": 6]
]

*/
```

When `dict1` and `dict2` have the same key, I expect the value to be replaced, but if that value is another dictionary, I expect it to be merged recursively.

Here is the solution I'd like:

```
protocol Mergeable {

    mutating func merge(obj: Self)

}

extension Dictionary: Mergeable {

    // if they have the same key, the new value is taken
    mutating func merge(dictionary: Dictionary) {
        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            let oldValue = self[key]

            if oldValue is Mergeable && value is Mergeable {
                var oldValue = oldValue as! Mergeable
                let newValue = value as! Mergeable

                oldValue.merge(newValue)

                self[key] = oldValue
            } else {
                self[key] = value
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but it gives me the error `Protocol 'Mergeable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

**EDIT:**
My question is different from [Swift: how to combine two Dictionary instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728477/swift-how-to-combine-two-dictionary-arrays) because that one is not a deep merge.

With that solution, it would produce:

```
dict3 = [
    "a": 1,
    "b": 4,
    "c": [
        "e": 5
    ]
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: how to combine two Dictionary arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728477/swift-how-to-combine-two-dictionary-arrays)

Comment: That one is not a deep merge.

Comment: In Swift, exactly what is the type of the dictionary you have in mind?

Comment: It can be anything, that is the problem, it is not necessarily just 2 levels deep and only strings and numbers.

Comment: You can't have a Swift dictionary of anything. Answer the question, please.

Comment: Also, tell me this: if "c" has a value that is a String in one dictionary and a dictionary in another, now what? I'm trying to show you that your spec is incoherent.

Comment: let dict = [String: AnyObject] ....

Comment: Edited the question to add your case `"f": 2` and then `"f": [...]`. Basically, if both values are dictionaries, you do a deep merge, if one of the values is not a dictionary, you just replace the old with the new value.

Answer (score 8):

In my view the question is incoherent. This is *an* answer, however:

```
func deepMerge(d1:[String:AnyObject], _ d2:[String:AnyObject]) -> [String:AnyObject] {
    var result = [String:AnyObject]()
    for (k1,v1) in d1 {
        result[k1] = v1
    }
    for (k2,v2) in d2 {
        if v2 is [String:AnyObject], let v1 = result[k2] where v1 is [String:AnyObject] {
            result[k2] = deepMerge(v1 as! [String:AnyObject],v2 as! [String:AnyObject])
        } else {
            result[k2] = v2
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Here is your test case:

```
    let dict1:[String:AnyObject] = [
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": [
            "d": 3
        ]
    ]

    let dict2:[String:AnyObject] = [
        "b": 4,
        "c": [
            "e": 5
        ]
    ]
    let result = deepMerge(dict1, dict2)
    NSLog("%@", result)
    /*
    {
        a = 1;
        b = 4;
        c =     {
            d = 3;
            e = 5;
        };
    }
    */
```

**3rd-party edit:** Alternate version using variable binding and newer Swift syntax.

```
func deepMerge(_ d1: [String: Any], _ d2: [String: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
    var result = d1
    for (k2, v2) in d2 {
        if let v1 = result[k2] as? [String: Any], let v2 = v2 as? [String: Any] {
            result[k2] = deepMerge(v1, v2)
        } else {
            result[k2] = v2
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thank you, actually trying your solution (which I thought was the same as mine) made me realize that comparing a dictionary with [String: AnyObject?] wasn't working, I have to compare to [String: AnyObject]. There is only one more problem, how to accept [String: AnyObject?]

Comment: I already said the question is incoherent. I answered the question as far as you asked it. I'm not hanging around here while you keep shuffling the goalposts around.

Comment: How is the question incoherent? I want a deep merge of a dictionary, like in any scripting language...

Comment: The question isn't incoherent at all, and this is a good solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func deepMerge(_ dict: Dictionary) {
        merge(dict) { (current, new) in
            if var currentDict = current as? Dictionary, let newDict = new as? Dictionary {
                currentDict.deepMerge(newDict)
                return currentDict as! Value
            }
            return new
        }
    }
}
```

How to use/test:

```
var dict1: [String: Any] = [
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": [
        "d": 3
    ],
    "f": 2
]

var dict2: [String: Any] = [
    "b": 4,
    "c": [
        "e": 5
    ],
    "f": ["g": 6]
]

dict1.deepMerge(dict2)

print(dict1)
```

Comment: The example does not work correctly. I have tested it. The problem seems to be that the replace in merge does not work properly. Try and replace "f": 2 with "f": ["g": 2] (in dict1) and you will no receive a  "f": ["g": 6] in the logged output but "f": ["g": 2] which is the old value (and incorrect). I wont downvote but please repair it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, fixed and updated the answer. Please verify. Test code can be found here: https://github.com/river2202/MonorailSwift/blob/0f6aaf12706f2a4f47ec735c084a38998fad5cab/MonorailSwiftTests/MonorailSwiftTests.swift#L84

Answer (score 0):

How about manually doing it.

```
func += <KeyType, ValueType> (inout left: Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType>, right: Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType>) { 
    for (k, v) in right { 
        left.updateValue(v, forKey: k) 
    } 
}
```

You can also try [ExSwift Library](https://github.com/pNre/ExSwift)