# Appending and Updating in a dictionary having a Dictionary as` Value`

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I want to add multiple values in same key of dictionary.
I have a Dic of type

```
 var dic1 = [String:[String:AnyObject]](

 dic1.updateValue(["name": cellName,"phone": Phone], forKey: "XYZ")
```

By this its updating value of key "XYZ" but I want to add more values in same key "XYZ".
Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: you need to add that custom operator to use his += suggestion `func +=<Key, Value> (inout lhs: [Key: Value], rhs: [Key: Value]) {
    rhs.forEach{ lhs[$0] = $1 }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you please help me in this. May be by steps or whatsoever suitable for you

Comment: This will solve the error += cannot be used with two [String:AnyObject] operands

Comment: @LeoDabus but I don't you how to use your code. please help me out .

Comment: just put that at the top level of any of your Swift files in your project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35740240/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus I did what you said but its still updating the values for key "XYZ" instead of adding

Comment: Please add the actual code with the actual result and the expected one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122229/discussion-between-navjot-singh-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: @LeoDabus I know It increases your efforts but can you please join the chat

Comment: I cant help you further  if you don't illustrate your problem. Once you have updated your question please let me know

Comment: @LeoDabus i illustrated everything in chat including coding,output and expected output thats why requesting you to join chat

Comment: You are updating the whole dictionary and you are supposed to update using the key

Comment: It is not easy to visualize the code inside the chat

Comment: Try dict["XYZ"] += theNewDictionar

Comment: @NavjotSingh when answers are satisfactory to what you want, given the amount of information that you provide, all you need to do is accept them and upvote.You also need to understand SO is not a personal help center, mostly why people answer here is to help other people who might end up with your problem, Thats why we try to generalise our answers as much as possible or if you want to be answered specifically then provide with your specific details. Please look up:- http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var mutDictionary = [String: NSMutableDictionary]()
        let keyVar = String(cellName[cellName.startIndex])
        if mutDictionary[keyVar] == nil {
          mutDictionary.updateValue([:], forKey: keyVar)
          mutDictionary[keyVar]?.setObject(["Name" : cellName, "Phone" : Phone], forKey: cellName)
        }
        else{
          mutDictionary[keyVar]?.setObject(["Name" : cellName, "Phone" : Phone], forKey: cellName)
        }
    print(mutDictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and elegant solution:-

```
var mutDictionary = [String: NSMutableDictionary]()

//Initialising your mutDictionary:-
mutDictionary = ["Fighters" : ["First" : ["NAME" : "The Tigress", "Phone" : "2131231231"]]]

//Adding a key-hashabale(or in this case String-NSMutableDictionary) pair.  
//`.updateValue` adds a new parent pair to your mutDictionary if your key value is not present if the key is present then it will update that key's value.
mutDictionary.updateValue(["First" : ["NAME" : "Uruguay", "Phone" : "903192301293"]], forKey: "The Bosses")
mutDictionary.updateValue(["FirstOfHisKind" : ["NAME" : "Panda", "Phone" : "123454362"]], forKey: "The Dragon Warrior")    

//Appending data to your mutDictionary:-
mutDictionary["Fighters"]?.setObject(["NAME" : "Guru Shifu", "Phone" : "121212121212"], forKey: "Second")

 print(mutDictionary)
```

The output that you get from this is something like this :-

```
   ["Fighters"          : { Second = {  NAME = Guru Shifu; 
                                        Phone = 121212121212;};
                            First = {  NAME = The Tigress;  
                                       Phone = 2131231231;};
                              },
    "The Bosses"        : {First = { NAME = Uruguay;
                                     Phone = 903192301293;};
                              },
    "The Dragon Warrior": {First = { NAME = Panda;
                                     Phone = 123454362;};
                            }]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Its not exactly what I want but gave me an idea and I got the desirable output. I am uploading it as a answer

Comment: @NavjotSingh when answers are satisfactory to what you want, given the amount of information that you provide, all you need to do is accept them and upvote.You also need to understand SO is not a personal help center, mostly why people answer here is to help other people who might end up with your problem, Thats why we try to generalise our answers as much as possible or if you want to be answered specifically then provide with your specific details, which you didn't. Please look up:- http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: can you help me in sorting this array "mutDictionary" by key "name"

Comment: This is a different question entirely. Avoid building up questions in comments, search net for them, if you dont find any solution ask a well asked question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
var value = Dict1["XYZ"]
value["address"] = "AAA BBB CCC 1234"
Dict1["XYZ"] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question:

1) you have to define a class and you can put many values inside it. Example:

```
 var user_location, user_mail, user_name, user_pass, user_urlPicture: String!

init(user_location: String!, user_mail: String!, user_name: String!, user_pass: String!, user_urlPicture: String!){

    self.user_location = user_location
    self.user_mail = user_mail
    self.user_name = user_name
    self.user_pass = user_pass
    self.user_urlPicture = user_urlPicture

}
// DictionaryConvertible protocol methods
required convenience init?(dict: [String:AnyObject]) {
    guard let user_location = dict["user_location"] as? String, user_mail = dict["user_mail"] as? String, user_name = dict["user_name"] as? String, user_pass = dict["user_pass"] as? String, user_urlPicture = dict["user_urlPicture"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    self.init(user_location: user_location, user_mail: user_mail, user_name: user_name, user_pass: user_pass, user_urlPicture: user_urlPicture)
}
var dict:[String:AnyObject] {
    return [
        "user_location": user_location,
        "user_mail": user_mail,
        "user_name": user_name,
        "user_pass": user_pass,
        "user_urlPicture": user_urlPicture
    ]
}
```

2) In your ("User") class you can add your values:

```
let user = User(yourLocation, user_mail: yourMail, user_name: yourName, user_pass: yourPass, user_urlPicture: yourUrlPicture)
```