# How to Post request in RxAlamofire with Array as parameters instead of Dictionary?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rxalamofire

I am trying to use RxAlamofire for Reactive requests. There is a method for creating `POST` request with -

```
public func request(_ method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod,
    _ url: URLConvertible,
    parameters: [String: Any]? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
    headers: [String: String]? = nil
)
```

But I cannot pass an Array `[[String : Any]]` to the parameters for obvious reasons. So how do I create a request with this array as parameters?

Being more specific, I can pass

```
let student = ["firstName":"Mayur", "lastName":"Deshmukh"]
```

as a parameter because it is of type `[String : Any]`

But I cannot pass array like

```
let students = [["firstName":"Mayur", "lastName":"Deshmukh"],
                ["firstName":"Kaustubh", "lastName":"Deshmukh"]]
```

As now the type of students is `[[String : Any]]`
So does Alamofire or RxAlamofire have any handy method for creating requests with JSON Array as parameter? Or do we have to take a harder way?

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do.  Do you have an array of dictionaries that you want to pass as a single dictionary for the query params?  If so just combine them all via `reduce` using something like shown here (for combining two dictionaries) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26728685/2326892

If you mean something else it's not clear what that would be.  Perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: If you are unsure of what the question is, you can add a comment to a question instead of adding irrelevant answer. It has nothing to do with reducing.