# Swift4. Dictionaries merging

Tags: swift, dictionary, random, swift4

There was a problem. There are two dictionaries with the same keys. I need to connect them to get the values in half from each dictionary randomly.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

```
var hiraganaDictionary1 = [
"a":"あ", "i":"い", "u":"う", "e":"え", "o":"お",
"A":"あ", "I":"い", "U":"う", "E":"え", "O":"お",
"ka":"か", "ki":"き", "ku":"く", "ke":"け", "ko":"こ",
"Ka":"か", "Ki":"き", "Ku":"く", "Ke":"け", "Ko":"こ",
"sa":"さ", "shi":"し", "su":"す", "se":"せ", "so":"そ",
"Sa":"さ", "Shi":"し", "Su":"す", "Se":"せ", "So":"そ",
"ta":"た", "chi":"ち", "tsu":"つ", "te":"て", "to":"と",
"Ta":"た", "Chi":"ち", "Tsu":"つ", "Te":"て", "To":"と",
"na":"な", "ni":"に", "nu":"ぬ", "ne":"ね", "no":"の",
"Na":"な", "Ni":"に", "Nu":"ぬ", "Ne":"ね", "No":"の"]


var katakanaDictionary1 = [
"a":"ア", "i":"イ", "u":"ウ", "e":"エ", "o":"オ",
"A":"ア", "I":"イ", "U":"ウ", "E":"エ", "O":"オ",
"ka":"カ", "ki":"キ", "ku":"ク", "ke":"ケ", "ko":"コ",
"Ka":"カ", "Ki":"キ", "Ku":"ク", "Ke":"ケ", "Ko":"コ",
"sa":"サ", "shi":"シ", "su":"ス", "se":"セ", "so":"ソ",
"Sa":"サ", "Shi":"シ", "Su":"ス", "Se":"セ", "So":"ソ",
"ta":"ソ", "chi":"チ", "tsu":"ツ", "te":"テ", "to":"ト",
"Ta":"ソ", "Chi":"チ", "Tsu":"ツ", "Te":"テ", "To":"ト",
"na":"ナ", "ni":"ニ", "nu":"ヌ", "ne":"ネ", "no":"ノ",
"Na":"ナ", "Ni":"ニ", "Nu":"ヌ", "Ne":"ネ", "No":"ノ" ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: how to combine two Dictionary instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728477/swift-how-to-combine-two-dictionary-instances)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merging(_:uniquingKeysWith:)` takes a function that decides how to deal with conflicts. You can use that function to randomly choose between the dictionaries.

```
let merged = hiraganaDictionary1.merging(katakanaDictionary1,
                                         uniquingKeysWith: { first, second in
                                            Bool.random() ? first : second })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let hiraganaDictionary1 = [
    "a":"あ", "i":"い", "u":"う", "e":"え", "o":"お",
    "A":"あ", "I":"い", "U":"う", "E":"え", "O":"お",
    "ka":"か", "ki":"き", "ku":"く", "ke":"け", "ko":"こ",
    "Ka":"か", "Ki":"き", "Ku":"く", "Ke":"け", "Ko":"こ",
    "sa":"さ", "shi":"し", "su":"す", "se":"せ", "so":"そ",
    "Sa":"さ", "Shi":"し", "Su":"す", "Se":"せ", "So":"そ",
    "ta":"た", "chi":"ち", "tsu":"つ", "te":"て", "to":"と",
    "Ta":"た", "Chi":"ち", "Tsu":"つ", "Te":"て", "To":"と",
    "na":"な", "ni":"に", "nu":"ぬ", "ne":"ね", "no":"の",
    "Na":"な", "Ni":"に", "Nu":"ぬ", "Ne":"ね", "No":"の"]


let katakanaDictionary1 = [
    "a":"ア", "i":"イ", "u":"ウ", "e":"エ", "o":"オ",
    "A":"ア", "I":"イ", "U":"ウ", "E":"エ", "O":"オ",
    "ka":"カ", "ki":"キ", "ku":"ク", "ke":"ケ", "ko":"コ",
    "Ka":"カ", "Ki":"キ", "Ku":"ク", "Ke":"ケ", "Ko":"コ",
    "sa":"サ", "shi":"シ", "su":"ス", "se":"セ", "so":"ソ",
    "Sa":"サ", "Shi":"シ", "Su":"ス", "Se":"セ", "So":"ソ",
    "ta":"ソ", "chi":"チ", "tsu":"ツ", "te":"テ", "to":"ト",
    "Ta":"ソ", "Chi":"チ", "Tsu":"ツ", "Te":"テ", "To":"ト",
    "na":"ナ", "ni":"ニ", "nu":"ヌ", "ne":"ネ", "no":"ノ",
    "Na":"ナ", "Ni":"ニ", "Nu":"ヌ", "Ne":"ネ", "No":"ノ" ]

var mixed = hiraganaDictionary1
for (key, _) in hiraganaDictionary1 {
    if Bool.random() {
        if let value = katakanaDictionary1[key] {
            mixed[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use [`.merging(…)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127173-merging) method instead of iterating in cycle of just one of dictionaries.

Comment: @user28434 done by Rob :-). If for some reason the key doesn't exist in both dictionaries, the value is lost ... and worst, it is lost randomly.

Comment: Ok, when I was writing that comment, Rob Napier's answer was quite different.

Comment: Yeah, I originally misunderstood the question and wrote about merging two half-dictionaries. I had missed the point that the keys were expected to the be the same (I was thinking of two independent sets of keys).

Answer (score 2):

Since you want one value for each existing key you can use Bool.random to determine from which dictionary to select the vale

```
var combined = [String:String]()
hiraganaDictionary1.keys.makeIterator().forEach {
    combined[$0] = Bool.random() ? hiraganaDictionary1[$0] : katakanaDictionary1 [$0]
}
```

Here is an alternative that for every second turn uses `Bool.random()` and every other turn uses the opposite of the last call to `Bool.random()`, this to take 50% from each dictionary

```
var combined = [String:String]()
var flag = true
var randomFlag: Bool
hiraganaDictionary1.keys.makeIterator().forEach {
    if (!flag) {
        combined[$0] = !randomFlag ? hiraganaDictionary1[$0] : katakanaDictionary1 [$0]
    } else {
        randomFlag =  Bool.random()
        combined[$0] = randomFlag ? hiraganaDictionary1[$0] : katakanaDictionary1 [$0]
    }
    flag = !flag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bool.random()` doesn't guarantee that half the keys would come from each dictionary. As a simple test :

```
var bool = Bool.random()
var count = 0
for _ in 1...100 {
    if bool { count += 1 }
    bool = Bool.random()
}

print(count)
```

This could yield `53, 61, 57, ...` on multiple runs.

If you want to make sure to get *"the values in **half** from each dictionary randomly"*, then you could observe that both dictionaries have the same keys, and thus the same count and do :

```
var mergedDict = [String : String].init(minimumCapacity: hiraganaDictionary1.count)

var bool = Bool.random()

let keys = hiraganaDictionary1.keys.shuffled()

for key in keys {
    mergedDict[key] = bool ? hiraganaDictionary1[key] : katakanaDictionary1[key]
    bool.toggle()
}
```

Note that the keys have been shuffled before being used. Otherwise, when iterating over them, the keys appear in the same order as they occur in the dictionary’s key-value pairs, which could be biased. Meaning, it could pre-determine which keys, from either dictionary, would appear in the resulting dictionary.

A more efficient way of shuffling the keys would be to shuffle the indices instead:

```
var mergedDict = [String : String].init(minimumCapacity: hiraganaDictionary1.count)

var bool = Bool.random()

let indices = hiraganaDictionary1.keys.indices.shuffled()

for index in indices {
    let key = hiraganaDictionary1.keys[index]
    mergedDict[key] = bool ? hiraganaDictionary1[key] : katakanaDictionary1[key]
    bool.toggle()
}
```