# Unable to concat two dictionaries

Tags: swift

I found the code snippet from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052094/2754218 and tested it in a Playground.

```
func +=<K, V> (inout left: [K: V], right: [K: V]){ 
  for (k, v) in right { 
    left[k] = v
  }
}

var test = ["1": "a"] += ["2": "b"]
```

The code causes: `Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two [String : String] operands.`

Any suggestion?

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Eric's I create a function with the operator "+":

```
func +<K, V> (left: [K: V], right: [K: V]) -> [K: V] {
  var newDic = left

  for (k, v) in right {
    newDic[k] = v
  }

  return newDic
}

var toto = ["1": "a"] + ["2": "b"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does not return anything, it passes the first value as an inout, meaning it will mutate the left hand object itself:

```
var test = ["1": "a"]

test += ["2": "b"]

print(test)  // ["2": "b", "1": "a"]
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't pay attention enough to this code. You're right!