# How to Add Many Items Into Dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

Just starting to learn Swift and was wondering if there was a way to quickly add multiple keys and values into a dictionary.

The reason I ask is that for the Array, we can quickly add new things to the list with the `.append` syntax, for example:

```
var newArray = ["ArrayItem1"]
var appendItems = ["ArrayItem2", "ArrayItem3", "ArrayItem4"]
newArray += appendItems
```

Is there such a short way to do it for Dictionaries?

Comment: Do you mean append multiple dictionaries? [How do you add a Dictionary of items into another Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051904/how-do-you-add-a-dictionary-of-items-into-another-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscript the dictionary using the key. Read the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html), under the Collection Type section.

```
var dictionary = [String:String]()

dictionary["oneKey"] = "a_value"
dictionary["twoKey"] = "a_value"
```

***EDIT***

If you wanted to do more than one at a time:

```
var dictionary: [String: String] = ["oneKey": "a_value", "twoKey": "a_value"]
```

Then append:

```
dictionary["threeKey"] = "a_value"
```

Comment: The OP never asked how to add them individually.

Comment: He wants to add multiple key values at once, not start with a dictionary and then append a single item

Answer (score 0):

In code:

```
var testdic:[String:Int] = ["item": 1, "item2": 2]
```