# Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two Dictionary<String, String>! operands during parsing in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I tried to append two dictionaries together using binary operator += in swift.But it shows an error

> "Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two Dictionary! operands ".

And the corresponding code is given below

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, 
   didEndElement elementName: String, 
   namespaceURI: String?, 
   qualifiedName qName: String?) {

            if elementName == "Item" {
                  inItem = false
                 objects += object
             }

     }
```

Dictionary Declaration is given below

```
var objects:Dictionary<String,String>! = nil
var object:Dictionary<String,String>! = nil
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33957196/1706564

Comment: these solutions are not working for me. can  anybody suggest a new method to sol;ve this please