# How to mutate/join two dictionary with same type using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, dictionary

```
let pageParams = ["page": "1",
                 "limit": "10"]

let commonParams = ["lang": "en",
                   "scale": "@3x"]

var resultParams =  ["page": "1",
                    "limit": "10",
                     "lang": "en",
                    "scale": "@3x"]

    // how to make "resultParams" by programmatically join "pageParams" with "commonParams" ? Is any short code available ?
```

I have two dictionaries have same data type. Key and values are string type. I need to join these two dictionaries programmatically. Swift have any better short code for this? Or Do we need to loop it and join?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/33957196/1949494

Comment: @Jelly Ok it worked.