# how to add an object into a NSDictionary with respect to a key

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have NSDictionary, now I am trying to add an object in a particular key.How can I do that ? below is my code.

```
let businessPhoneDic = ["locationname" : "",
                                "area" : "",
                              "number" : "",
                                "type" : "",
                       ];
let emailDic:NSMutableDictionary? = ["email" : "",];

let businessPhoneDic2 = ["locationname" : "hello",
                                 "area" : "",
                          "phonenumber" : "",
                                 "type" : "",
                        ];

var mainDictionary = ["businessPhone" : businessPhoneDic as AnyObject,"email" : emailDic as AnyObject,
        ];
```

Now I want to add "businessPhoneDic2" into mainDictionary for key "businessPhone".How can I do that into Swift 3

Comment: mainDictionary["businessPhone"] = businessPhoneDic2

Comment: Yes I was trying that but its just replace the old dictionary with the new value,So when I print mainDictionary["businessPhone"]  after updating its replace businessPhoneDic with businessPhoneDic2.

Comment: Yes because a dictionary contains unique keys and only 1 value corresponding to that key. So you cannot store multiple values for a single key.

Comment: Yes I want to append another value for with the previous dictionary

Comment: businessPhoneDic and businessPhoneDic2 contain same key-value pairs. So same logic, only unique key-value pairs are allowed.

Comment: Can I merge businessPhoneDic and businessPhoneDic2 and after that I can update mainDictionary's "businessPhone" key.

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Like "locationname" : "" and "locationname" : "hello", which one do you want to keep?

Comment: For adding elements of 1 dictionary into another refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051904/how-do-you-add-a-dictionary-of-items-into-another-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, you can't have two values mapped to the same key. The following code will replace the old key:

**Swift 3**

```
mainDictionary["businessPhone"] = businessPhoneDic2
```

Just use a new key if you need both values in your dictionary, or maybe store an array of dictionaries as values as such:

```
var mainDictionary : [String : [NSDictionary]] = ["businessPhone" : [businessPhoneDic]]
```

Then:

```
mainDictionary["businessPhone"]?.append(businessPhoneDic2)
```

Comment: I use this code
var mainDictionary : [String : [NSDictionary]] = ["businessPhone" : [businessPhoneDic as NSDictionary]]
        mainDictionary["businessPhone"]?.append(businessPhoneDic2 as NSDictionary)

        print("=====", mainDictionary["businessName"] as AnyObject)

but its return <null>

Comment: Of course. You do not have a value for the key businessName in your mainDictionary. You should call mainDictionary[businessPhone].first!["businessName"] granted the businessPhoneDic dictionary has a businessName key

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry.Yes now its fine.I just want that Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all **do not use `MSMutable...`  collection types in Swift.**

Use native Swift Dictionary

```
let emailDic = ["email" : ""]
```

Second of all annotate a dictionary with different types as `[String:Any]`

```
var mainDictionary : [String:Any] = ["businessPhone" : businessPhoneDic, "email" : emailDic]
```

---

If the value for key `businessPhone` is an array you can append the value. If it's a single dictionary you have to create an array.

This code considers both cases:

```
let businessPhone = mainDictionary["businessPhone"]

if var phone = businessPhone as? [[String:Any]] {
    phone.append(businessPhoneDic2)
    mainDictionary["businessPhone"] = phone
} else if let phone = businessPhone as? [String:Any] {
    mainDictionary["businessPhone"] = [phone, businessPhoneDic2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 mainDictionary["your key"] = businessPhoneDic2 as AnyObject // cast as per suggestions
```

Comment: why down voting ?

Comment: Yes I was trying that but its just replace the old dictionary with the new value,So when I print mainDictionary["businessPhone"] after updating its replace businessPhoneDic with businessPhoneDic2.

Comment: use different key because businessPhone key is already exist .

Comment: So how can I merge two dictionary and update it for that particular key?

Comment: you want to merge existing dictionary with new one ?

Comment: Can I merge businessPhoneDic and businessPhoneDic2 and after that I can update mainDictionary's "businessPhone" key.

Comment: you can't merge as dictionary as per your question. because there are all keys are same  businessPhoneDic and businessPhoneDic2 if you set businessPhoneDic2 then it will be override ride with old dictionary.

Comment: you need to use array for "businessPhone". or add dictionary to that array.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.x**

// Initialize the Dictionary

```
var dict = ["name": "Foo", "surname": "Bar"]
```

// Add a new key with a value

```
dict["email"] = "foo.bar@email.com"
print(dict)
```