# Closure tuple does not support destructuring in Xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode9-beta

After the gloss project for Swift 4 in Xcode 9

I am getting following error which i have no idea

> Closure tuple parameter '(key: _, value: _)' does not support
>   destructuring

**Code:**

```
extension Dictionary
{
    init(elements: [Element]) {
        self.init()
        for (key, value) in elements {
            self[key] = value
        }
    }

    func flatMap<KeyPrime, ValuePrime>(_ transform: (Key, Value) throws -> (KeyPrime, ValuePrime)?) rethrows -> [KeyPrime:ValuePrime] {
        return Dictionary<KeyPrime, ValuePrime>(elements: try flatMap({ (key, value) in
            return try transform(key, value)
        }))
    }
}
```

Error comes at this point `try flatMap({ (key, value)in`

Comment: `Dictionary.init(elements:)` cannot be found in the Swift Standard Library. You define it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I am updating the answer

Comment: i have updated the answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's start with the definition of `flatMap` for a dictionary which is the following:

```
func flatMap(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
```

You see that the `transform` closure takes only **one parameter** of type `Element` where `Element` is just a `typealias` for a tuple:

```
public typealias Element = (key: Key, value: Value)
```

So the first **and only** argument of the closure should be a tuple of two elements (`key` of type `Key` and `value` of type `Value`).

---

Now, if you look at your code (which compiles in Swift 3), you will see that this is not the case, and you should be asking why does this even work in Swift 3.

```
try flatMap({ (key, value) in
    return try transform(key, value)
})
```

Your closure takes 2 arguments instead of one (`key` of type `Key` and `value` of type `Value`). This works in Swift 3 thanks to a feature called *destructuring* where the compiler will automatically transform a tuple of 2 elements into 2 arguments.

<s>But this feature is weird, rarely used and gives unexpected results most of the time so it has been removed in Swift 4.</s>
**Edit**: As pointed out by OOPer, this feature has been temporarily removed in Swift 4 beta but should be re-added before the final version is out.

Instead you should be writing:

```
try flatMap({ tupleArgument in
    return try transform(tupleArgument.key, tupleArgument.value)
})
```

And your `flatMap` function becomes:

```
func flatMap<KeyPrime, ValuePrime>(_ transform: (Key, Value) throws -> (KeyPrime, ValuePrime)?) rethrows -> [KeyPrime:ValuePrime] {
    return Dictionary<KeyPrime, ValuePrime>(elements: try flatMap({ element in
        return try transform(element.key, element.value)
    }))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaination. It's third party library which i am trying to make compatible with swift4.

Answer (score 8):

It's a side-effect of this proposal for Swift 4:

[SE-0110 Distinguish between single-tuple and multiple-argument function types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md).

But some features included in this proposal caused some **regression** which is addressed in this post of the [evolution-announce mailing list](https://lists.swift.org/mailman/listinfo/swift-evolution-announce):

[[swift-evolution-announce] [Core team] Addressing the SE-0110  usability regression in Swift 4](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2017-June/000386.html)

So, you can expect in the future beta or GM version of Xcode 9, your code would compile well again. Until then, you can use this sort of workaround:

```
internal func flatMap<KeyPrime , ValuePrime>(_ transform: (Key, Value) throws -> (KeyPrime, ValuePrime)?) rethrows -> [KeyPrime : ValuePrime] {
    return Dictionary<KeyPrime,ValuePrime>(elements: try flatMap({ pair in
        let (key, value) = pair
        return try transform(key, value)
    }))
}
```

---

By the way, in Swift 4, `Dictionary` has some new initializers which take `Sequence` of `(Key, Value)` pair. For example:

[init(uniqueKeysWithValues: S)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init)

Answer (score 6):

I just encountered this error as a result of using `enumerated().map()`:

> Closure tuple parameter does not support destructuring

I typed the code:

```
["foo"].enumerated().map
```

And then pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> 3 times until Xcode autocompleted the closure boilerplate.

The autocomplete seemingly has a bug that causes the above error. The autocomplete produces double-parenthesis `((offset: Int, element: String))` rather than single-parenthesis `(offset: Int, element: String)`.

I fixed it manually and was able to continue:

```
// Xcode autocomplete suggests:
let fail = ["foo"].enumerated().map { ((offset: Int, element: String)) -> String in
    return "ERROR: Closure tuple parameter does not support destructuring"
}

// Works if you manually replace the "(( _ ))" with "( _ )"
let pass = ["foo"].enumerated().map { (offset: Int, element: String) -> String in
    return "works"
}
```

Possibly the result of using Xcode 10.0 beta (10L176w)

Comment: I confirm this, but the fix doesn't solve all issues. Consider this one:
`let allLocales: [(String, String)] = Locale.isoRegionCodes.map({ ($0, Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: $0) ?? "Unknown") }).sorted {((c0: String, r0: String), (c1: String, r1: String))  -> Bool in
     return r0 < r1
}`
What is wrong with `.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }` option one might wonder.
Suppose I want to omit `c1, c2`, replace them with ` _  `.  See no way to do it.

Comment: @PaulB that at least seems to make sense for the error *Closure tuple parameter does not support destructuring*. Meaning you (currently) can't use a destructured tuples as the parameters of a closure. Hopefully will be added to the language in the future. Switch to *structured* tuple parameters and it works fine: `.sorted { (locale0, locale1) -> Bool in`. The parameters in my code sample are NOT tuples but Xcode autocomplete has presented them as such via the extra `( )`.

Comment: Yes, @pkamb, this is the case. It's possible to use parameter labels whichever you want, but decomposing tuples "in place" is not supported (yet?) as the corresponding error message states. So it comes as a surprise that in some cases you actually can somehow destructure a tuple (or tuples?) and write something like:
`let pass = ["foo"].enumerated().map { (offset: Int, _: String) -> String in
    return "works"
}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Xcode 11.1 and Swift 5, and ran into this error while using `enumerated().map()`. I think this example simplifies things a little, but in general this is what fixed it for me. The true error was the compiler unable to infer to return value:

```
// Correct Syntax
let resultModels: [ResultModel] = array.enumerated().map { index, model in
  // code
}

// Results in the error Closure tuple does not support destructuring
let resultModels = array.enumerated().map { index, model in
  // code
}
```